# erlang macro expansion bug

Tags: macros, erlang

`macro` module:

```
-module(macro).

-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

-define(EXPAND(_T), ??_T).

macro_test() ->
    ?assertEqual("Test", ?EXPAND(Test)),
    ?assertEqual("Test.test", ?EXPAND(Test.test)).
```

Is resulting :

```
6> c(macro).         
{ok,macro}
7> eunit:test(macro).
macro: macro_test (module 'macro')...*failed*
in function macro:'-macro_test/0-fun-1-'/1 (macro.erl, line 9)
**error:{assertEqual_failed,[{module,macro},
                     {line,9},
                     {expression,"? EXPAND ( Test . test )"},
                     {expected,"Test.test"},
                     {value,"Test . test"}]}


=======================================================
  Failed: 1.  Skipped: 0.  Passed: 0.
error
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known bug?

TIA

Comment: You should explain more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @SteveVinoski I thought that was obvious. I am trying to use [Stringifying Macro Arguments](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html#id85036) feature of erlang macro

Comment: Yes, that much is obvious. But that's not your end goal, is it? I was really trying to ask why you need `Test.test` to be stringified exactly into `"Test.test"`, i.e., what are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're incorrectly assuming that the Erlang compiler treats `Test.test` as a single token. If you pass the `-P` option to `erlc` and examine the output, you'll see that the preprocessor breaks it into multiple tokens. Here's the interesting part of `macro.P` produced by `erlc -P macro.erl`:

```
macro_test() ->
    begin
        fun(__X) ->
               case "Test" of
                   __X ->
                       ok;
                   __V ->
                       error({assertEqual,
                              [{module,macro},
                               {line,8},
                               {expression,"? EXPAND ( Test )"},
                               {expected,__X},
                               {value,__V}]})
               end
        end("Test")
    end,
    begin
        fun(__X) ->
               case "Test . test" of
                   __X ->
                       ok;
                   __V ->
                       error({assertEqual,
                              [{module,macro},
                               {line,9},
                               {expression,"? EXPAND ( Test . test )"},
                               {expected,__X},
                               {value,__V}]})
               end
        end("Test.test")
    end.
```

Comment: That explains it! I also missed `io:format("Call ~s: ~w~n",["myfunction ( 1 , 2 )",myfunction(1,2)])` (in documentation) where space is added. So macro arguments are kind of language pretty printed